# Can EntityFrameworkCore RoleManager FindByIdAsync populate Claims?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-middleware, asp.net-core-identity

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole>` is not populating the `Claims` property when calling `FindByIdAsync(string id)` [github link to method](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5480aa182bad3fb3b729a0169d0462873331e306/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/RoleStore.cs#L304)

Can [eager loading](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#eager-loading) be enabled for the `AddEntityFrameworkStores` in `services.AddIdentity` in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){...}`?

```
services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloning/forking https://github.com/aspnet/Identity and adding an extension method in [RoleStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5480aa182bad3fb3b729a0169d0462873331e306/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/RoleStore.cs) with `.Include(...)` will work for the moment.

```
public virtual Task<TRole> GetByIdAsync(string id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        var roleId = ConvertIdFromString(id);
        return Roles.Include(r => r.Claims).Include(r => r.Users).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id.Equals(roleId), cancellationToken);
}
```